# Powershell Add-Content

Tags: syntax, powershell

I can't get add-content to add both a string and the output of a cmdlet so it would look something like this;

```
Add-content -path $logfile -value "This is my text"+(Get-Date)
```

I realise I can just add another line to set a variable to the result of get-date but and then pass the variable into my add-content command but I just wondered if I could do it in a single line, like a said Im being anal lol

Cheers

Andy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try `"This is my text $(Get-Date)"`

In PowerShell, strings in double quotes can contain variables and expressions.  If it's not a simple expression (e.g. `"This is a $value"`), then you need to wrap the expression in `$()` (e.g. `"This is a $($value + 1)"`).

Note that strings in single quotes are "verbatim strings" and do not allow escape characters or expressions.

Comment: Nice work, Im I right in saying the $ puts PS back into expression mode?

Comment: Right, $() makes PS evaluate expressions inside strings with double quotes.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer [MohitC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/637021/282110) method but you can also enclose your value in parenthesis:

```
Add-content -path $logfile -value ('This is my text '+(Get-Date))
```